# Подставить массив в условие WHERE

Tags: php, mysql, sql

у меня есть перечень id

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
```

как мне вывести из БД записи с этими id ?

я рассматриваю вариант пройтись циклом и изменить значение 1

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM test WHERE id = 1 ';
```

возможно можно как то подставить массив в `WHERE id = 1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

используйте [implode()](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.implode.php)

```
$array = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM test WHERE id in ('.implode(",", $array).')';
```

Comment: про SQL инъекции слышали когда-нибудь?

Comment: Да, и откуда им браться в данном массиве,

Comment: значит не слышали. Инъекции как раз и появляются там, где  программист думает "да откуда им взяться".

Comment: разумеется, что смысла в таком статическом массиве нет - точно так же эти значения можно прописать сразу в запросе а не в переменной $array. Такая задача может возникнуть только если $array содержит динамические данные.

Comment: Вопрос был в том как в SQL запрос передать массив, на что был даден ответ. Защита от sql инъекций это уже другая история... Собственно и защиту несложно сделать, перебрать массив - $array = array_map('intval', $array);

Comment: НЕТ, ЭТО НЕ ДРУГАЯ ИСТОРИЯ. Если беретесь отвечать, то ответ должен быть нормальный, а не говнокод, который  сломается на следующий день